# sssd allows switching via su to users blocked from ldap_access_filter for users that can log in

Tags: ldap, authentication, sssd

My department is switching to using sssd with ldap for logins on all of our linux hosts. I've got it all working, but there was one issue I was hoping to resolve before continuing testing in our dev environment. We specify the ldap groups that can log in using the ldap_access_filter option and that works as intended, but it appears to be possible for users with root access to switch to ldap users (using su from root) that should be blocked from logging in using the ldap_access_filter. I'd like to be able to not allow user switching or getting info via the id command to these users that don't require access to the machines I'm concerned with. Is it possible to keep this from happening by modifying my ldap_search_base, ldap_user_search_base, or ldap_group_search_base or maybe some other method.

This is my sssd config

```
[sssd]
#debug_level = 9
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
domains = domain.edu

[pam]
#debug_level = 9
offline_credentials_expiration = 30

[domain/domain.edu]
#debug_level = 9
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
access_provider = ldap
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
ldap_uri = ldaps://sub.domain.edu:636
ldap_search_base = ou=people,o=cuid
ldap_default_bind_dn = cn=svcaccount,ou=proxy,o=cuid
ldap_access_order = filter
ldap_access_filter = groupMembership=cn=devtest,ou=groups,ou=people,o=cuid
ldap_default_authtok_type = obfuscated_password
ldap_default_authtok = [redacted]
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/openldap/certs/devldap.pem
ldap_tls_reqcert = never
enumerate = true
cache_credentials = True
account_cache_expiration = 30
entry_cache_timeout = 14400
subdomain_inherit = ignore_group_members, ldap_purge_cache_timeout
ignore_group_members = True
ldap_purge_cache_timeout = 0
access_provider = ldap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer

```
ldap_user_search_filter = groupMembership=cn=devtest,ou=groups,ou=people,o=cuid
```

This made it so that only users that were in the group devtest could have their information polled by sssd.

Comment: hei user23497333, welcome, please remember to accept your answer, else we will be reminded until the end of the universum to solve this issue. thanks